# How to stop recursion after some time in C

Tags: c

I need to stop recursion after, let's say, 30 seconds in C. One of my attempts was using a `goto` - despite recommendations of not using it, but i can't use it between different functions. The code is below:

```
void func_t(int n, int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int height, Data *data, time_t start_time){        
    int cont;
    data->level_recursions[height] =  data->level_recursions[height] + 1;

    if ( n<= 1) return; 

    for (cont = 1; cont <= a; cont++){
        data->height = height + 1;
        func_t( (n/b) - c, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, 1 + height, data );
    }

    for (cont = 1; cont <= d; cont++) {
        data->height = height + 1;
        func_t( (n/e) - f, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, 1 + height, data );
    }

    clock_t begin = clock();
    for (cont = 1; cont <= fn(n, g); cont++);
    clock_t end = clock();
    data->level_work[height] = data->level_work[height] + ((double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a global const parameter(current time) that you init for the first running time.
2. If 30 sec + the value of the global < current time -> hit return or do what ever you want)

Maybe this is the if statement to enter to the recursion

Comment: but in this case, i would just return, right? So, i would execute all of the recursions. Is there a way to stop the function?

Comment: Do not create a global variable. Pass the `start_time` as argument instead.